# How to disable the "News and Interests" but still keep the Weather updates in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

I find it useful to have the current weather conditions in my taskbar, but I hate the "News and Interests" feature that they push to their users from non-English speaking countries, since nobody even cares about those news.

Therefore, is there any combination of utilizing the Registry, Services or even 3rd party applications where I would be able to keep the simplest weather conditions in my taskbar and get rid of those news?

I tried to hide each and every news provider manually, but it seems they have set the maximum on the amount of hidden new providers, so that may not work.

[image: Weather widget]